# i have challenges implementing OOP in python

Tags: python, oop

I am facing challenges implementing OOP in python to enable me to call the functions whenever i want , so far i have no syntax errors which makes quite challenging for me . The first part of the code runs ehich is to accept data but the function part does not run.

I have tried different ways of calling the function by creating an instance of it.

```py
  print (list)
      def tempcheck(self,newList): 
          temp=newList[0]
          if  temp==27:
           print ("Bedroom has ideal temperature ")
          elif temp>=28 or temp<=26:
                      print ("Bedroom Temperature is not ideal ,either too low or too cold. ")
                      print  ("Please to adjust the temperature to the optimum temperature which is 27 degree Celsuis")


             # now to initialize args
      def __init__(self,temp,puri1,bedwashroom,newList):
           self.temp=temp
           self.puri1=puri1
           self.bedwashroom=bedwashroom

           tempcheck(newList)




            # now calling the functions 

           newvalue=tempcheck(list)
   # where list contains the values from the input function.
```

I expected the function to  to check the specific value at the location in the list provided which is called list and also for the function to return a string based on the `if` statements.

Comment: Where are you defining the `class`?

Comment: "so far i have no syntax errors" loading this into Pycharm/VScode gives me ~30 errors/warnings. The indentation matters, and it's all over the place.

Comment: do you intended to define class named "print"? it is reserved word so plz change its name and may be you wanted to do "class print_cls(list):"

Comment: @Craig the definition of  the class was done in earlier lines of code but i couldn't past the entire  code here as i am not allowed over here however this is the paste bin  link of the code https://pastebin.com/t5VaR5hh.  I am trying to get the if statements to check what is in specific locations of the list i provide and , and pass the appropriate string based on the value in the location. I am basically a beginner trying to master OOP in python

Comment: @JaredSmith i couldn't past the entire  code here as i am not allowed over here however this is the paste bin  link of the code https://pastebin.com/t5VaR5hh.  I am trying to get the if statements to check what is in specific locations of the list i provide and , and pass the appropriate string based on the value in the location. I am basically a beginner trying to master OOP in python

Comment: @DevKhadka i couldn't past the entire  code here as i am not allowed over here however this is the paste bin  link of the code https://pastebin.com/t5VaR5hh.  I am trying to get the if statements to check what is in specific locations of the list i provide and , and pass the appropriate string based on the value in the location. I am basically a beginner trying to master OOP in python

Answer (score 0):

i got it right ,i figured out an alternative to my bug thanks for the critique however any further addition is welcome, 
the main goal was to create a function that takes input and passes it to list to be used later i guess this code is less cumbersome 
   the link to the full  code is pasted below